# Sort Acrobat XI Pro Bookmarks with Adobe's JavaScript

Tags: javascript, acrobat, bookmarks

I have a large Acrobat file (Acrobat XI Pro) which I have Bookmarked.  The resulting Bookmarks are, however, all over the map so the goal is to sort the Bookmarks A-Z.  I searched for an appropriate Acrobat Action without success.  I did, however, locate some possible JavaScript in the the Acrobat XI SDK:

```
 http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat.html
```

I downloaded it (at bottom of EULA for version XI):

```
 http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/sdk/eula.html
```

I found a reference on batch sequences with three sections of interest: (1) Gather bookmarks to an array; (2) Sort Bookmark subroutine; and (3) Copy bookmarks from an array.

Ideally I would like to combine all scripts into a single JavaScript call in the Action.  My first attempt was to create an Action with two separate JavaScript calls (1) as the GATHER and (2) & (3) as the COPY with the SORT integrated

The first JavaScript compiles after I put the script into the JavaScript call in the Action.  However, the second JavaScript would not compile.  The error was an "unterminated string literal" at this line of code:
          +'var that =
               app.openDoc("'+ global.bmArray[i][1]+'.pdf",  [ERROR PRESENTS HERE]
                    this);\r\t'
          +'if ( this != that ) this.closeDoc();\r'

I researched this error online and tried various solutions without success.

When I failed with building within an Action, I took the put the two JS scripts – the Gather and the Sort - into a .txt file and saved it as a .sequ which, when , should automatically populate into Acrobat as an Action.  When I did this Acrobat reported it as corrupt and unloadable so that didn't work either.

My hope is a review of Adobe’s code with a solution to the unterminated string literal error a guide that the location guidance on the insert location of the SORT into the COPY part of the script.

My goal, as noted, is to have an Action that merely re-sorts the Bookmarks.  The JavaScript I found seems to fit the bill as it marks the Bookmark links to the respective document.  If I am incorrectly reading this and could be steered in the right direction, it would be appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, there is a mishmash of single and double quotes in that line. Take your code into a text editor with code coloring and quote balancing, and you probably will see where the problem occurs. It also looks as if that JavaScript assembles JavaScript code.

Comment: Hadn't looked at the quote issue and will do so.